# Do I need change or add new array for this table to work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var ALEast = (
    {name: "Stanford University", nickname: "Stanford", ownership: "private", SATh: 1570, SATl: 1380, tuition: 44757},
    {name: "University of California, Berkeley", nickname: "UC Berkeley", ownership: "public", SATh: 1500, SATl: 1250, tuition: 13844},
    {name: "University of California, Santa Cruz", nickname: "UC Santa Cruz", ownership: "public", SATh: 1280, SATl: 1000, tuition: 13398},
    {name: "San Francisco State University", nickname: "SFSU", ownership: "public", SATh: 1110, SATl: 880, tuition: 6468},
    {name: "San Jose State University", nickname: "SJSU", ownership: "public", SATh: 1160, SATl: 880, tuition: 9496},
    {name: "Sonoma State University", nickname: "Sonoma State", ownership: "public", SATh: 1090, SATl: 880, tuition: 7276},
    {name: "California State University, East Bay", nickname: "CalState East Bay", ownership: "public", SATh: 1010, SATl: 800, tuition: 6550, room: 6435},
    {name: "University of San Francisco", nickname: "USF", ownership: "private", SATh: 1270, SATl: 1070, tuition: 41450},
    {name: "Santa Clara University", nickname: "SCU", ownership: "private", SATh: 1380, SATl: 1190, tuition: 43812},
    {name: "Mills College", nickname: "Mills College", ownership: "private", SATh: 1250, SATl: 1040, tuition: 42918}
    );
ALEast.sort();
document.write('<table>');
document.write('<tr><th>Teams</th></tr>');

for(var i = 0; i < ALEast.length; i++)
{
    document.write('<tr><td>' + ALEast[i] + '</td></tr>');
}

document.write('</table>');
```

Don't close my question if you don't feel as if this is not a question but do I need to change

```
  Var ALEast = (
```

to

```
  Var ALEast = New Array(
```

for my table to be implemented?

Comment: Yes, or use square brackets `[…]` instead of parentheses.

Comment: Sorry. Don't see what the question is...

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax declaring the array is wrong, use [] instead of ().

```
var ALEast = []
```

Also in your for loop you need to call the property you want to display.

```
document.write('<tr><td>' + ALEast[i].name + '</td></tr>');
```

Here is a working plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/kKtI91505KWhcwf9YGry

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working sample! Just click run.  As a bonus, I made sort() actually do something.

```js
var ALEast = [
    {name: "Stanford University", nickname: "Stanford", ownership: "private", SATh: 1570, SATl: 1380, tuition: 44757},
    {name: "University of California, Berkeley", nickname: "UC Berkeley", ownership: "public", SATh: 1500, SATl: 1250, tuition: 13844},
    {name: "University of California, Santa Cruz", nickname: "UC Santa Cruz", ownership: "public", SATh: 1280, SATl: 1000, tuition: 13398},
    {name: "San Francisco State University", nickname: "SFSU", ownership: "public", SATh: 1110, SATl: 880, tuition: 6468},
    {name: "San Jose State University", nickname: "SJSU", ownership: "public", SATh: 1160, SATl: 880, tuition: 9496},
    {name: "Sonoma State University", nickname: "Sonoma State", ownership: "public", SATh: 1090, SATl: 880, tuition: 7276},
    {name: "California State University, East Bay", nickname: "CalState East Bay", ownership: "public", SATh: 1010, SATl: 800, tuition: 6550, room: 6435},
    {name: "University of San Francisco", nickname: "USF", ownership: "private", SATh: 1270, SATl: 1070, tuition: 41450},
    {name: "Santa Clara University", nickname: "SCU", ownership: "private", SATh: 1380, SATl: 1190, tuition: 43812},
    {name: "Mills College", nickname: "Mills College", ownership: "private", SATh: 1250, SATl: 1040, tuition: 42918}
 ]
    ;
ALEast.sort(function(a,b){
    var textA = a.name.toUpperCase();
    var textB = b.name.toUpperCase();
    return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;
});
document.write('<table>');
document.write('<tr><th>Teams</th><th>Nickname</th><th>Ownership</th></tr>');

for(var i = 0; i < ALEast.length; i++)
{
    document.write('<tr>');
    document.write('<td>' + ALEast[i].name + '</td>');
    document.write('<td>' + ALEast[i].nickname + '</td>');
    document.write('<td>' + ALEast[i].ownership + '</td>');
    document.write('</tr>');
}
document.write('</table>');
```